# When do we need the NDK for OpenCV Android

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk

I am just starting to learn OpenCV for Android, I have played around with it a bit and it all works fine.

I installed the NDK and managed to run some of the sample apps which included it.

I am not clear on what we need the NDK for. I could not find it referenced anywhere in the documentation.

Is there OpenCV functionality which is not available in the regular library 2.4.8 ?

Is it just so we can use modules written in c++ that others have made available, without rewriting them in java ?

Comment: Ndk is used to generate the shared object files (.so) .Once so files are generated ,modules in c/c++ can be used at run time by using java native interface.

Comment: Thanks, I know that but which features of OpenCV need C++ ? Specifically

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have been using NDK for my application and following are my
    observations.

1. Yes, it gives the advantage of using plenty of c++
   modules which are made available.
2. If you already have a bit of
               experience in computer vision application programming using openCV
               library in C++, you don´t have to learn new syntaxes in java(can be quite
               irritating some times).
3. Using NDK for your app can give you a slight upperhand in terms of
   performance when image processing you do is    computationally
   demanding (I am not quite sure about this because    the openCV
   library made available for Android is just a wrapper    around the
   same header files and stuff and should almost give the same performance as NDK. I have never really compared    the
   performance myself but have read in various blogs that NDK is faster).
4. One thing
       you really have to be careful when using NDK is calls from JAVA to
       NDK side or the other way round, these calls can be really expensive in terms of performance(Needs careful planning).
5. Passing few parameters like array of MAT from JAVA to NDK are a bit
           of headache, but you can find few workarounds.

Based on these and other factors you might have found out from various sources and also by your programming strengths you can decide if you want to use NDK or not. There was never really a set of guidelines i could find that says you can use NDK if so and so conditions are satisfied, people just start with which ever programming style they are more comfortable with.

Comment: Thank you, I feel that I have enough to get started. I have noticed that it is far easier to find c++ sample code.

Comment: Although you will find more C++ samples (many of them will be somehow outdated in relation with OpenCV library progress), Java will be significantly easier to program, unless you already have good C++ experience.

Answer (score 2):

In Android documentation they advice to use NDK in case of

```
# CPU-intensive operations that don't allocate much memory,
# such as signal processing, physics simulation, and so on.
```

If everything you want to do can be computed with OpenCV built'in functions, you may not need NDK as processing routines of OpenCV are already in C/C++.

However, if you have to process the images matrix intensively (I mean direct access to pixels), you will improve performances using the NDK.